# !GetAtt InternalLB.DNSName

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I am trying to fetch the dns of internal classic load balancer and pass it in the launch configuration of ec2 instance as a user data. Creating a db in ec2 instance and in the config file trying to get the dns of the internal classic load balancer but I am unable to get it. `!GetAtt InternalLB.DNSName` I have used this in the user data but the db is not connected but when I manually pass the dns it works.I need to fetch the dns on its on using this userdata script.

```
  ec2instance:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Properties:
      # AvailabilityZone: us-east-2a
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash
           cd /var/www
           mkdir inc
           cd inc
           sudo echo "<?php

           define('DB_SERVER', '!GetAtt InternalLB.DNSName'); 
           define('DB_USERNAME', 'db');
           define('DB_PASSWORD', 'db');
           define('DB_DATABASE', 'db');

           ?>" > dbinfo.inc
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
          Ebs:
            DeleteOnTermination: "true"
            VolumeSize: "8"
            VolumeType: gp2
      ImageId: ami-0bdcc6c05dec346bf
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: wahaj(webserver)
      SecurityGroups:
        - Ref: wahajwebserver
  myASG:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZones:
        - "us-east-2a"
        - "us-east-2b"
      AutoScalingGroupName: myASG
      LoadBalancerNames:
        - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${elb}-MyLoadBalancer"
      MinSize: "2"
      MaxSize: "2"
      DesiredCapacity: "2"
      HealthCheckGracePeriod: 300
      LaunchConfigurationName:
        Ref: ec2instance
      VPCZoneIdentifier:
        - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${SourceStackName}-SubnetC"
        - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${SourceStackName}-SubnetD"
  internalelbsg:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: internal-elb
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          Fn::Sub: "${SourceStackName}-VpcID"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 3306
          ToPort: 3306
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !GetAtt wahajwebserver.GroupId
          Description: For traffic from Internet
      GroupDescription: Security Group for demo server
  InternalLB:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Scheme: internal
      Listeners:
        - LoadBalancerPort: "80"
          InstancePort: "80"
          Protocol: HTTP
        - LoadBalancerPort: "3306"
          InstancePort: "3306"
          Protocol: TCP
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref internalelbsg
      LoadBalancerName: internalelbsg
      Subnets:
        - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${SourceStackName}-SubnetC"
        - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${SourceStackName}-SubnetD"
      HealthCheck:
        Target: HTTP:80/index.html
        HealthyThreshold: "3"
        UnhealthyThreshold: "5"
        Interval: "30"
        Timeout: "5"
```

The main issue is in  `define('DB_SERVER', '!GetAtt InternalLB.DNSName');` this line I am not fetching the dns in the right way. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `GetAtt` inside of `Sub`, you have to use the `VarName: VarValue` syntax as described in the [Fn::Sub documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html). Additionally, you have to wrap `VarName` with `${}`, i.e. `${VarName}`.

I believe this syntax should work:

```yaml
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub
          - |
            #!/bin/bash
            cd /var/www
            mkdir inc
            cd inc
            sudo echo "<?php

            define('DB_SERVER', '${InternalLBDNSName}'); 
            define('DB_USERNAME', 'db');
            define('DB_PASSWORD', 'db');
            define('DB_DATABASE', 'db');

            ?>" > dbinfo.inc
          - InternalLBDNSName: !GetAtt InternalLB.DNSName
```

Comment: @Shifa Please try the above. I did not test it, so if you need to change it slightly, let me know and I can update the answer with the final result. Thank you.